# Code completion in XCode 4 working strangely

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Since a few months ago, the code completion turned context-insensitive: it offers ALL the symbols  starting with same letters in the same file, including words from the comments. On the other hand, it does not suggest anything from other files.
The problem survived cleaning all project data, reinstalling and upgrading Xcode and even upgrading the operation system.

Answer (score 0):

from time to time I am having similar issues. Removing the DerivedData folder works for me.

here you'll find the same suggestion http://blog.slidetorock.com/xcode-4-code-sense-autocompletion-problems

Comment: unfortunately, removing the derived data does not work. Moreover, code completion does not work even if i start a brand new project

Comment: Who knows, if different project can't interfere somehow in Xcode. maybe u should remove EVERY DerivedData folder on your disk.